# try to force app on Android 4.x (API lower than 20) to use TLSv1.2

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit2, okhttp, sslsocketfactory

Our backend is updated from SHA-1 & TLS 1.0 to **SHA-2 certificate & TLS 1.2** . It breaks the HTTPS communication of our Android app on platforms with **API level lower than 20**   (**Android 4.1-4.4**).

(Our Android project is using **Retrofit 2.4.0** & **okhttp 3.10.0**)

I try to fix above issue by forcing our app on Android 4.x using **TLS 1.2**, my code is inspired by [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@sreekumar_av/certificate-public-key-pinning-in-android-using-retrofit-2-0-74140800025b) (but I excluded public key pinning of the tutorial code):

I firstly created a `TLSSocketFactory`:

```
public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

    public TLSSocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { systemDefaultTrustManager() }, null);
        internalSSLSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
        if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
            ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
        }
        return socket;
    }

    public X509TrustManager systemDefaultTrustManager() {
        try {
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                    TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
            TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
            if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:"
                        + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
            }
            return (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(); // The system has no TLS. Just give up.
        }
    }
}
```

Then, apply above `TLSSocketFactory` to `OkHttpClient` :

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_1, TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                .cipherSuites(
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
                .build();

builder.connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));


builder.readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
builder.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
builder.writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// apply TLSSocketFactory

        try {
            TLSSocketFactory socketFactory = new TLSSocketFactory();
            builder.sslSocketFactory(socketFactory, socketFactory.systemDefaultTrustManager());
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
```

Then, create a instance of `Retrofit` by using above `OkHttpClient`:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(myUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client) // my OkHttpClient
                .build();
```

But when I run my app now on Android 4.x communication to our backend, I still get the **error**:

```
OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Why? What am I missing?

(In `TLSSocketFactory`'s constructor, I also tried `sslContext.init(null, null, null);` but it doesn't help, same error.)

(**The new certificate is fine, it works with Android 5.0+, but new certificate and old certificate are from different issuers**)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why it's necessary to call this method `systemDefaultTrustManager`

To use system defaults, try replacing

```
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { systemDefaultTrustManager() }, null);
```

by

```
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
```

Comment: is the certificate trusted ?

Comment: How can I verify that? Is it so that if it is a self-signed certificate, it won't be trusted by Android, no matter Android 4.x or 5.x or etc.?

Comment: You said you are changing the backend's certificate. Are both certificates provided/signed by the same certificates seller ? Is the backend reachable from the internet to be tested by SSLLABS ?

Comment: Hmm... it was updated by another team, which I have to ask tomorrow, but can we make an assumption now? Does it affect if old and new are signed by different certificate seller with precondition that both sellers are CA?

Comment: Yes. Your client checks in its truststore if it has any CA for this certificate, or the certificate itself.

Comment: The Exception you encounter means that the truststore doesn't want this certificate.

Comment: But even if the old certificate and new one are from different sellers, as long as both sellers are CA, isn't it so that the Android truststore will trust both?

Comment: CAs are not always updated on all versions. Probably you will check for your Android version, which CAs are configured. I don't know where to check this, I won't be more efficient than you for this point.

Comment: is the CA different ?

Comment: No, I confirmed, they are from different issuer, but as long as both CAs are trusted by Android 5.0+, is there a problem with different issuers? How would that related with the problem I am having?

Comment: If the issuer is not trusted by Android 4, you will get this issue. And the Exception you get means it's not trusted.

Comment: I checked, it is from digicert, which should be a trusted CA.

Comment: "which should be" You need to check if "should" means "is".

Answer (score 0):

Try propositions posted [here on okHttp library's Github](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4053) - it's well known problem